# What does the $values parameter of apc_add() do?

Tags: php, apc

http://php.net/apc_add

I don't understand what the `$values` parameter actually does - it is not even shown in function signature.

Can anybody help explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a 4th parameter, rather an alternate first parameter. There are 2 ways of using `apc_add()`.

You can either set a single item by passing a key and value:

```
apc_add('Key', 'Value');
```

Or you can set multiple variables at the same time by passing them in an array:

```
$data = array('Key1' => 'Value1', 'Key2' => 'Value2');
apc_add($data);
```

This is equivalent to doing:

```
apc_add('Key1', 'Value1');
apc_add('Key2', 'Value2');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no fourth parameter. The function is overloaded so $values is actually used in the second way you can call it.

Here are the two ways to call it from the documentation:

> bool apc_add ( string $key [, mixed $var [, int $ttl = 0 ]] )
>
> array apc_add ( array $values [, mixed $unused [, int $ttl = 0 ]] )